# Updating Habit Tracker App State in Flutter After Saving Changes

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I'm developing a habit tracker app with Flutter, aiming to help users track and manage their habits effectively. The app allows users to set a habit name and a timer goal, which they can update via a settings dialogue. However, I'm facing an issue with updating the habit name and timer on the main screen after the user clicks the "save" button in the settings dialogue.

The app design and functionality can be seen in these images:

- Desired design and functionality: [image: Desired Design]
- Current state:

[image: Current State]

Here is a simplified version of my code related to the issue:

```
 class HabitTile extends StatelessWidget {
      // add a setstate
    
      final bool setState;
      final String habitName;
      final VoidCallback? onTap;
      final VoidCallback? settingsTapped;
      final int timeSpent;
      final int timeGoal;
      final bool habitStarted;
      HabitTile({
        Key? key,
        required this.setState,
        required this.habitName,
        required this.onTap,
        required this.settingsTapped,
        required this.timeSpent,
        required this.timeGoal,
        required this.habitStarted,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      List habitList = [
        ['Exercise', false, 0, 120],
        
      ];
      //convert seconds into min
      String formatToMinSec(int totalSeconds) {
        String secs = (totalSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
        String mins = (totalSeconds ~/ 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    
        //if min is one digit number
        if (mins.length == 1) {
          mins = '0$mins';
        }
        return '$mins:$secs';
      }
    
      //calculate proress percentage
      double calculateProgress(int timeSpent, int timeGoal) {
        return timeSpent / timeGoal;
      }
    
      
      
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20, right: 20),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[100],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: onTap,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 80,
                        width: 80,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            CircularPercentIndicator(
                              lineWidth: 8,
                              radius: 40,
                              percent: calculateProgress(timeSpent, timeGoal) > 1.0
                                  ? 1.0
                                  : calculateProgress(timeSpent, timeGoal),
                              progressColor:
                                  calculateProgress(timeSpent, timeGoal) > 0.5
                                      ? (calculateProgress(timeSpent, timeGoal) >
                                              0.75
                                          ? Colors.green
                                          : Colors.orange)
                                      : Colors.red,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Icon(
                                habitStarted ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          habitName,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 4),
                        Text(
                          '${formatToMinSec(timeSpent)} / ${formatToMinSec(timeGoal)} = ${(calculateProgress(timeSpent, timeGoal) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)} %',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  //navigate to settings page
    
                  onTap: () {
                    //navigate trought an alert dialog
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text("Settings\nDaily goal time\nfor this habit"),
                            content: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                // develop a textformfield to update the habitList name
    
                                Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        habitName,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: (){},
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
    
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    const Text("Time Goal"),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          formatToMinSec(timeGoal),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        IconButton(
                                        onPressed: (){
                                        
                                        },
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                                      ),
                                        
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                //create a save button
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text("Save"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.settings,
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Home_page.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //oveerall habit summary
  List habitList = [
    ['Exercise', false, 0, 120],
  
  ];

  // create a method to start the timegoal
 

  void habitStarted(int index) {
    var startTime = DateTime.now();

    int elapsedTime = habitList[index][2];

    setState(() {
      habitList[index][1] = !habitList[index][1];
    });

    if (habitList[index][1]) {
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        setState(() {
          if (!habitList[index][1]) {
            timer.cancel();
          }

          //calculate the time elapses by subtracting the start time from the current time
          var currentTime = DateTime.now();
          habitList[index][2] = elapsedTime + currentTime.second -
              startTime.second +
              60 * (currentTime.minute - startTime.minute) +
              3600 * (currentTime.hour - startTime.hour);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  void settingsOpened(int index) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Settings for ${habitList[index][0]}"),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text(
          'Consistency is the key to success ',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: habitList.length,
        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
          return HabitTile(
            setState: true,
            habitName: habitList[index][0],
            onTap: () {
              habitStarted(index);
            },
            settingsTapped: () {
              settingsOpened(index);
            },
            habitStarted: habitList[index][1],
            timeSpent: habitList[index][2],
            timeGoal: habitList[index][3],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've attempted to use `setState` to update the widget state, but the changes do not reflect on the UI as expected. Ideally, after updating the habit name or timer in the settings dialogue and clicking `"save,"` the main screen should reflect these updates immediately.

Could someone help me identify what I'm missing or suggest a better approach to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow the design you have given as an example you should use [CupertinoDatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePickerclass.html)

[image: CupertinoDatePicker]

I don't recommend saving and storing data in a widget in such a way and I would prefer another solution (see MVVM) but y can use the following:

To get access to your Stateful Widget methods from outside

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  /// This line is responsible for.
  static HomePageState? of(BuildContext context) => context.findAncestorStateOfType<HomePageState>();

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}
```

Then inside HomePageState create some method that is responsible for state modification:

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
...
    /// Your logic to modify state. Also, you can put some parameters.
    void methodToModifyState() {
        setState(() {

        });
    }
...
}
```

So, as a result, you can call your method to update the state from outside:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    /// You can put some parameters to the function here.
    HomePage.of(context).methodToModifyState()
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
child: const Text("Save"),
)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm a novice on Flutter, can you please help me to add a logic to modify the state and on the elevated button to create the parameters and functions?

Comment: You should create a model class for your habit instance and instead of 
List<HabitModel> habitList = [
  HabitModel()
  ]


And when you click the save button you should transfer your updated model:
HomePage.of(context).methodToModifyState(updatedModel);
The model should contain a unique ID of the habit by which you will update a specific entry from the list in the setState(() { habitList.firstWhere((habit) => habit.id == updatedModel.id) = updatedModel;
});